# Grouping & aggregating large dataset by multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group my data by multiple columns and then aggregate values in other columns.  While I've found numerous examples of this online, I'm running into issues when I attempt to apply the same practices to my `DataFrame`.  I'm thinking it might be due to size (1.5mm+ rows).

I have a `DataFrame` with name and address info, along with two 'source' columns:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   Firstname   Lastname       Address     Zip5   Source_A  Source_B
0      'John'    'Smith'    '1 May St'  '10001'         1         0
1       'Lou'    'Brown'  '2 Perry Ln'  '20983'         0         1
2    'Elaine'    'Brown'  '5 Park Ave'  '34785'         1         0
3      'John'    'Smith'    '1 May St'  '10001'         0         1
```

I wish to group rows with similar name and address information, then aggregate the 'source' columns with the `max()` function.  My code is as follows:

```
In [43]: grouped = df.groupby(['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Zip5'], as_index = False, sort = False)

In [44]: grouped.max()
Out[44]:
   Firstname   Lastname       Address     Zip5   Source_A  Source_B
0      'John'    'Smith'    '1 May St'  '10001'         1         1
1       'Lou'    'Brown'  '2 Perry Ln'  '20983'         0         1
2    'Elaine'    'Brown'  '5 Park Ave'  '34785'         1         0
```

This output is exactly what I want -- essentially, the rows are deduplicated on `['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Zip5']`, with `Source_A` and `Source_B` taking on maximum values from the original dataframe.

However, while this works on smaller DataFrames,  the code does not finish running on very large sets of data (1.5mm rows).  I ran this code on a large dataset about ~45 min ago and it has yet to finish.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  I am also curious as to why simply identifying duplicates with `df.duplicated(['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Zip5'], keep = 'last')` works very quickly whereas `groupby` struggles.

Comment: It will take some time to group and sort millions of records, Is there an index on the underlying database table? If not, consider creating a view based on your query

Comment: @Vasya I do have a unique ID on my original dataframe, but for purposes of the example, I omitted it.  How would that help?  I'm also a bit confused about your last sentence.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try sorting before using the groupby? `df.sort_values(['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Zip5'], inplace=True)`

Comment: @Erfan I tried that and it doesn't appear to improve anything.  Thanks though!

Comment: how much time does it take on a 100K rows subset?

Comment: also, how many unique values do you have in each of the `groupby()` columns?

Comment: @Marat Thanks for your response.  On the full dataframe (1.5mm), it takes 50+ minutes.  On a 100k random sample, it takes ~90 seconds.  As for unique values, I'm not sure how many duplicates there are in each column alone... However, I do know that of the entire dataset, roughly 400k rows (25-30%) are duplicates on `['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Zip5']`.

Comment: @LeChase: can you post your table definition? what's the back-end database? In some DBMS, it's possible to create a view based on a query. A view will be accessible just like any table.

Comment: can you try running it without `as_index=False`? If it doesn't complete in 50 minutes, then it is most likely a bug/suboptimal implementation in pandas. In this case, you can workaround by grouping smaller subsets, concatenating and grouping again

Comment: @Marat unfortunately running with `as_index = False` yielded the same result (I was running that originally earlier today, but the output format was not what I wanted).  I'll continue looking for a workaround -- thanks for your help!

Comment: please run it **without** `index=False`

Comment: @Marat apologies, I had a typo in my response, I meant to say i was originally running it without `as_index = False`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be quicker since I don't know if pivot_table or melt or the combination of both are both quicker than using groupby but here's an alternate solution

I used melt function to stack the values from Source_A and Source_B into one column

```
df_melt=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Firstname','Lastname','Address','Zip5'],value_vars=['Source_A','Source_B'])
```

Then applied a pivot table to the result

```
df_pivot=df_melt.pivot_table(index=['Firstname','Lastname','Address','Zip5'],columns='variable',aggfunc='max').reset_index()
```

Hope it helps!